# New computer system, not sure how to use it, how do I get my old one back?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

My hard drive was dying so it needed to be replaced. I got a new one and when I got it has this new system on it, but it's very complicated to use. Is there a way I can get it back the the way my old one was?

[image]

This new one doesn't seem very customizable at all. One thing that bothers me is that there is no bottom taskbar, so I can't see any windows I have open.

Answer (score 1):

Get to your terminal, and type `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`, this will install the Gnome Shell desktop environment, but it will also include Gnome Fallback Session.

Log out, and on the session screen, select the button near your user name, click on "Gnome Fallback", enter password and there you have a fallback session.

Other alternatives might be getting used to Unity, installing Ubuntu 10.04 LTS for a Gnome 2.3 desktop, or alternatives like Cinnamon Desktop environment, which is the most easy alternative for you.

Try googling Cinnamon, there is an article about how to install on webupd8.org

Good luck ;)

Comment: I tried that, but it isn't the same. I am now trying Gnome3. Still no bottom taskbar.

Comment: You can get bottom taskbars for Gnome-Shell, (gnome3 is not the desktop environment), using extensions. You should try the Linux MInt Gnome Shell Extensions, which try to resemble your needings, or some extensions you may find on extensions.gnome.org web page, which gives you an option to enable on a click (when using Firefox). Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more info, the Desktop Environment you now have is Unity, wich is the default nowadays of Ubuntu, before it was Gnome. If it is Gnome you want you can install it by running the command: sudo apt-get install gnome-shell.
Then reboot and on the main screen choose Gnome.

More info at: http://techhamlet.com/2011/10/install-gnome-shell-in-ubuntu-11-10/